# Sampling distribution from two independent Bernoulli populations

Tags: distributions, sampling, bernoulli-distribution

Let's assume that we have samples of two independent Bernoulli random variables, $\mathrm{Ber}(\theta_1)$ and $\mathrm{Ber}(\theta_2)$.

How do we prove that $$\frac{(\bar X_1-\bar X_2)-(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\theta_1(1-\theta_1)}{n_1}+\frac{\theta_2(1-\theta_2)}{n_2}}}\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)$$?

Assume that $n_1\neq n_2$.

Comment: Z_i= X_1i - X_2i is a sequence of iid rv of finite mean and variance. Hence it satisfies the Levy-Linderberg central limit theorem from which your results follow. Or are you asking for a proof of the clt itself?

Comment: @ThreeDiag How are you applying the LL version of the CLT? I don't think that's correct. Write an answer for me to check the details.

Comment: All the details are already there. For LL to apply you need a sequence of iid rv with finite mean and variance. The variable Z_i = X_i1 and X_i2 satisfies all three requirements. Independence follows from independence of the two original bernoulli vars and you can see that E(Z_i) and V(Z_i)  are finite by applying standard properties of E and V

Comment: @ThreeDiag I'm not saying that the conditions are not there. I'm saying that your conclusion doesn't follow.

Comment: Why would it not follow?

Comment: @ThreeDiag Not every theorem which may be applied is useful. Have you tried to prove it, instead of just applying the theorem? I've tried, and I didn't find a way to reach the conclusion I wanted.

Comment: The statement of the theorem is exactly that your quantity you are looking for follows a normal 0,1. And as per my first comment : if you instead want a proof of the clt (have you read the theorem?) say so and also show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: "samples of two independent Bernoulli random variables" - incorrect expression. Must be: "two independent samples from Bernoulli distributions".

Comment: @Viktor It was my edit, and it may be cumbersome, but it's distributions that need to be independent here.

Comment: @amoeba Distributions cannot be independent. If one says "independent distributions", he/she has to explain what he/she means.

Comment: @Viktor Yes, I wrote it hastily replying to your comment. My formulation says "random variables", and you will surely agree that random variables *can* be independent.

Comment: @amoeba Sample of independent Bernoulli random variables may mean that we have a sequence of independent random vectors $(X_{1,j},X_{2,j})$ with independent components. However in this case we do not need $n_1$ and $n_2$. So here we have *two* independent samples.

Comment: @Viktor Okay, then it should be "two independent samples of two independent random variables".

Comment: @amoeba Yes, it may be so. But usually: "In mathematical terms, given a random variable X with distribution F, a random sample of length n (where n may be any of 1,2,3,...) is a set of n independent, identically distributed (iid) random variables with distribution F." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)

Comment: @Viktor Sure, but this quote describes what happens inside each sample and says nothing about the relationship between random variables generating sample #1 and sample #2.

Comment: Please add "as $n_1,n_2\to \infty$".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put 
$a=\frac{\sqrt{\theta_1(1-\theta_1)}}{\sqrt{n_1}}$, $b=\frac{\sqrt{\theta_2(1-\theta_2)}}{\sqrt{n_2}}$,
$A=(\bar{X}_1-\theta_1)/a$, 
$B=(\bar{X}_2-\theta_2)/b$. We have
$A\to_d N(0,1),\ B\to_d N(0,1)$. 
In terms of characteristic functions it means
$$ \phi_A(t)\equiv {\bf E}e^{itA}\to e^{-t^2/2},\ \phi_B(t)\to e^{-t^2/2}.$$
We want to prove that 
$$D:=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}A-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}B\to_d N(0,1) $$

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent,
$$\phi_D(t)=\phi_A\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}t\right)\phi_B\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}t\right)\to e^{-t^2/2},
$$
as we wish it to be.

This proof is incomplete. Here we need some estimates for uniform convergence of characteristic functions. However in the case under consideration we can do explicit calculations. Put $p=\theta_1,\ m=n_1$.
\begin{align}
\phi_{X_{1,1}}(t) &= 1+p(e^{it}-1),  \\
\phi_{\bar X_{1}}(t) &= (1+p(e^{it/m}-1))^m,  \\
\phi_{\bar X_{1}-\theta_1}(t) &= (1+p(e^{it/m}-1))^m e^{-ipt},  \\
\phi_{A}(t) &= (1+p(e^{it/\sqrt{mp(1-p)}}-1))^m e^{-ipt\sqrt{m}/\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \\[5pt]
 &= \left( \left(1+p(e^{it/\sqrt{mp(1-p)}}-1)\right)e^{-ipt/\sqrt{mp(1-p)}}\right)^m \\[5pt]
&=\left( 1-\frac{t^2}{2m}+O(t^3m^{-3/2}) \right)^m 
\end{align}
as $t^3m^{-3/2}\to 0$. Thus, for a fixed $t$,
$$\phi_D(t)=\left( 1-\frac{a^2t^2}{2(a^2+b^2)n_1}+O(n_1^{-3/2}) \right)^{n_1} 
\left( 1-\frac{b^2t^2}{2(a^2+b^2)n_2}+O(n_2^{-3/2}) \right)^{n_2} \to e^{-t^2/2}
$$
(even if $a\to 0$ or $b\to 0$), since $\left|e^{-y}-(1-y/m)^m\right|\le {y^2}/{2m}\ $ when $\ y/m<1/2$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566469/uniform-bounds-for-1-y-nn-exp-y/ ).

Note that similar calculations may be done for arbitrary (not necessarily Bernoulli) distributions with finite second moments, using the expansion of characteristic function in terms of the first two moments.

Comment: This seems correct. I'll get back to you later on, when I have time to check everything. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Proving your statement is equivalent to proving the (Levy-Lindenberg) Central Limit Theorem which states

If $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variable with finite mean $\mathbb{E}(Z_i) = \mu $ and finite variance $\mathbb{V}(Z_i) = \sigma^2$ then $$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{Z} - \mu) \to^d N(0,\sigma^2)$$

Here $\bar{Z} = \sum_i Z_i/n$ that is the sample variance.

Then it is easy to see that if we put

$$ Z_i = X_1i - X_2i $$ with $X_{1i}, X_{2i}$ following a $Ber(\theta_1)$ and $Ber(\theta_2)$  respectively the conditions for the theorem are satisfied, in particular

$$ \mathbb{E}(Z_i) = \theta_1 - \theta_2 = \mu $$

and

$$ \mathbb{V}(Z_i)= \theta_1(1-\theta_1) +\theta_2(1-\theta_2)= \sigma^2 $$

(There's a last passage, and you have to adjust this a bit for the general case where $n_1 \neq n_2$ but I have to go now, will finish tomorrow or you can edit the question with the final passage as an exercise )

Comment: I could not obtain what I wanted exactly because of the possibility of $n_1\neq n_2$

Comment: I will show later if you can't get it. Hint: compute the variance of the sample mean of Z and use that as the variable in the theorem

Comment: Three, could you please add the details for when $n_1 \neq n_2$? Thanks

Comment: Will do as soon as find a little timr. There was in fact a subtlety that prevents from using LL clt without adjustment. There are three ways to go, the simplest of which is invoking the fact that for large n1 and n2, X1 and X2 go in distribution to normals, then a linear combination of normal is also normal. This is a property of normals that you can take as given, otherwise you can prove it by characteristic functions.

Comment: The other two require either a different clt (Lyapunov possibly) or alternatively treat n1 = i and n2= i +k. Then for large i you can essentially disregard k and you can go back to apply LL (but still it will require some care to nail the right variance)

Comment: Then, could you please add the details? Because, as it stands, the answer is very incomplete(only for a specific case), and I cannot accept it as is... Thanks ;)