# Proportions: why changing to population mean estimator doesn't change the distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, proportion

I saw in a few places (e.g. [here](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268/)) when you compare proportions of 2 samples, under a null hypothesis that they are equal, you eventually get to this:

$$
\frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{\sqrt{P(1-P)(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m})}} \sim N(0,1)
$$

At which point there's a mental "jump" where you estimate $P$ from the total of two samples, and stick it in the above formula, i.e.:

$$
\hat P = \frac{\sum x_i + \sum y_i}{n + m} \\
\frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{\sqrt{\hat P(1- \hat P)(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m})}} \sim N(0,1)
$$

My question is why is it legal to simply stick $\hat P$ instead of $P$ and still assume that it distributes on the standard normal distribution. Is there any proof of this?

**UPDATE**:

So I tried to simulate it myself, and indeed, when $n \neq m$, the histogram of the proportion statistic looks to fit very well the standard normal distribution.

[image]

**However**, if $n = m$, there seems to be a gap opening in the middle of the distribution:

[image]

Code (in Python):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sqrt, stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Statistic
p = 0.2
n = 700
m = 300
X = np.random.binomial(n, p, 10000)
Y = np.random.binomial(m, p, 10000)
x_bar = (1/n) * X
y_bar = (1/m) * Y
est_p = (1/(n+m)) * (X + Y)
var = est_p * (1 - est_p) * (1/n + 1/m)
statistic = (x_bar - y_bar)/(sqrt(var))
plt.hist(statistic, density=1, color='blue', edgecolor='black', bins=200, alpha=0.5, label='Statistic')

# Normal
mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red', label='Normal')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: "My question is why is it legal to simply stick P^ instead of P and still assume that it distributes on the standard normal distribution. Is there any proof of this?"  Yes, Slutsky's Theorem. Keep in mind that these distributional results are about convergence in distribution as $m$ and $n$ approach infinity.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235070/1st-yr-statistics-question-create-an-approximate-alpha-level-test-of-h-0/.

Comment: @StubbornAtom this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The substitution of $\hat p$ for $p$ is 'legal' only in the sense
that it is a reasonable approximation in some circumstances. 
The sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ have to be large enough for
normal approximations to be valid.

Suppose $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n_1, \theta_1),$
$Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n_2, \theta_2),$ and we want to use binomial
counts $X$ and $Y$ to test $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2$ against
 $H_a: \theta_1 \ne \theta_2.$ Then we use $\hat p_1 = X/n_1$ to estimate
$\theta_1$ and  $\hat p_2 = Y/n_1$ to estimate
$\theta_2.$  And, under $H_0,$ we use $\hat p = (X+Y)/(n_1 + n_2)$ to estimate
$\theta = \theta_1 = \theta_2.$

If sample sizes are sufficiently large, then 
$Z = \frac{\hat p_1 - \hat p_2}{\widehat{SE}} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ where
$SE = \sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)(1/n_1 + 1/n_2)},$ and $SE$ 
is estimated by $\widehat{SE} = 
\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)(1/n_1 + 1/n_2)}.$

In your example from the link we have $n_1 \approx 300$ and $n_2 \approx 200$ The following simulation
shows that those sample sizes are suitable for a normal approximation
of the null distribution for $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2,$ at least
in the 'tail', where judgments to accept or reject are made.

```
set.seed(731)
th1 = .6; n1 = 300; x=rbinom(10^5, n1, th1)
th2 = .6; n2 = 200; y=rbinom(10^5, n2, th2)
p1 = x/n1;  p2 = y/n2;  p = (x+y)/(n1+n2)
d = p1-p2;  se = sqrt(p*(1-p)*(1/n1 + 1/n2));  z = d/se
hist(z, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2)
  abline(v =c(-1.96,1.96), col="red", lty="dotted")
mean(abs(z) > 1.96)
[1] 0.05046
```

[image]

In the simulations, the z-statistic leads to a test at very nearly the 5% level. The distribution of $Z$ is discrete, slightly smoothed out in the histogram, but still approximately normal in the tails.

By contrast, if sample sizes are $n_1 = 20, n_2 = 15,$ then the simulated
distribution of the z-statistic is a poor approximation to normal. The *simulated distribution* is essentially correct, but
it is not clear that that the *standard normal distribution* leads to a valid test. [The R code for this simulation is omitted because there are only a few changes in code from the previous one.]

[image]

The simulated distribution of $Z$ is discrete. Simulated probabilities of its 204 values are plotted below.

[image]

Most 'rules of thumb', recommending adequate sample sizes for such tests, are
based on simulations.

Comment: When we replace the Standard Deviation with it's estimate for normal distribution, we get that the statistic actually distributes according to the T-distribution. So I just wonder how can you replace it here with the estimator and claim it's still a plain ol' normal distribution? Is there some proof of it, or is it just an "intuition".

Comment: Great question. That's because the 0/1-variables (smoker vs non-smoker) are sampled from Bernoulli distributions. The Bernoulli distribution has only one parameter p (the parameter you actually want to test). The sd of Bernoulli distribution is only a transformation of p not a separate independent parameter. As sigma is not estimated separately, it's not a t distribution. Does that make sense?

Comment: Some have argued on empirical rather than theoretical grounds that t may give more accurate results than z when sample sizes are _very_ small. However in this Answer, sample sizes where simulation shows z to be a useful fit are large enough that there would be no real difference btw t and z.

Comment: @StoryTeller0815 sounds like a good intuition, but I would really love to see a full proof.

Comment: It's not exactly the same but this may be helpful:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262233/sampling-distribution-from-two-independent-bernoulli-populations Maybe you can continue your research from their.

Comment: I need to dig deeper to understand this reference - but I do notice (as mentioned in the proof there) that when n is equal to m, there seems to be a problem with the approximation. @BruceET any idea why is that? Also - is it valid to say, we only care about the rejection area, and there it looks like the normal distribution?